# How can you create a libtool object from a dll and lib file?

Tags: c, autotools, libtool, shared-libraries

I have been hacking away at this problem for days now and I can't seem to get this seemingly simple problem solved. There are functions provided by a DLL that I need to use from another DLL. I have verified that all of the missing symbols I need are in the static library extracted by dlltool, but no matter what I try it will not link into the shared library. This is my current attempt which seemed promising but has simply lead me to a new error.

libtool: link: cannot build libtool library 'libnvml.la' from non-libtool object on this host

This is my Makefile.am

```
AM_CPPFLAGS = -I$(top_srcdir)/include

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libnvml.la 

libnvml.la: libnvml.a
    ar x libnvml.a `ar -t libnvml.a` && $(LIBTOOL) --mode=link $(CC) -g -O -o $@ `ar -t libnvml.a`

libnvml.a: nvml.def
    $(DLLTOOL) -d $< -D nvml.dll -k -l $@ && ranlib libnvml.a

nvml.def: $(NVML)/lib/nvml.lib
    $(LIB2A)/bin/reimp.exe -d  $<
```

Does anyone know how I can convert this lib file into libtool library (.la) so I can link it to my dll?

Comment: `libtool`, as it says, cannot build a `.la` from the non-libtool objects listed by `ar -t libnvml.a`. `libtool` object files have extension `.lo` and are generated by *compiling* the source file through `libtool`. But why do you believe that having this `.la` library will be necessary or helpful?

Comment: @Mike, it would make the system more homogenous.  From what I understand about your comment it would require a de-compile of the .o files.  I was able to find a way to link a static library to a dynamic library so for now I don't need to go to such lengths.

Comment: Yes, I was going to tell you such a way, but I wondered why libtool was involved at all. Glad problem solved.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP has discovered he was barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: Mike, Since it is possible to create a .so/.dll from a static library .a it must also be possible to create a .la file from one.  The solution I used was not ideal since it wouldn't be reasonable in a large application to put off linking of static files until the final linking stage.